# Animated color grid based on mouse click event

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, colors, signal-processing

I am looking to create a color grid which takes some raw user inputs like: defined script running time, # of random signals, # of samples, and normalization 0 or 1. On pressing the mouse, one of the columns or box should change to red color indicating "HIGH" while the other boxes/colums remain blue, yellow or green.

So far I have the following code but I'm not making any headway apart from being able to display an example color grid. What steps could I take to perform raw inputs and generate random signals?

```
from pylab import arange, cm, draw, rand
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from time import sleep
import time

start_time = time.time()
plt.ion()
a = arange(25)
a = a.reshape(5,5)
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5, 5))
for i in range(100):
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    b = 5*rand(5,5)
    cax = ax.matshow(a-b, cmap=cm.jet, vmin = -10, vmax = 25)
    if i == 0:
        fig.colorbar(cax)
    draw()  
    sleep(0.01)
plt.show()
print("--- %s seconds ---" %(time.time() - start_time))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', update)`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/event_handling/test_mouseclicks.html) to set a callback function (e.g. `update`) to be called whenever the user clicks the mouse:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import time

start_time = time.time()
def generate_data():
    a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
    b = 10 * np.random.rand(5, 5)
    result = a - b
    n = result.size
    np.put(result, np.random.randint(n), 25)
    return result

def update(event):
    data = generate_data()
    mat.set_data(data)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    return mat 

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
mat = ax.matshow(generate_data(), cmap=plt.get_cmap('jet'))
plt.colorbar(mat)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', update)
plt.show()
print("--- %s seconds ---" %(time.time() - start_time))
```